# How can I do a case-insensitive search using "Find in project" in kile?

Tags: kile

The "Find in Project" function is quite useful, however it is case-sensitive, at least when using `%s` in the text box right of the dropdown box with `Template: Normal`. Is there documentation on what the `%s` stands for and what alternatives are allowed?

Comment: I do not use Kile but I know little bit about Unix. Check if Kile supports regular expressions. I do not know what "Find in Project" mean but if you are using Unix like system or if you feel brave enough to install Cygwin on your Windows machine I would suggest that you learn about grep and sed.

Comment: The `%s` stands for string and simply pastes the string of the field above into the search phrase. I found this out by selecting Template: Command where the `%s` becomes a `\\%s\{`.

Comment: I can cause a "Grep Tool Error" by putting `\\section{%s` in the second field. The error message is "Invalid regular expression: bad repetition syntax". From this we now know that grep is used as the underlying tool. (It might be easier looking in the source code...)

Answer (score 2):

In line with my comments, I tried a bit around.

Kile uses grep as its search tool.

Passing `-i` as an option won't work. However, you can use regular expression up to a degree. Example:

Using Template `normal` and search for mechanik, where it is either spelled mechanik or Mechanik, then use `[mM]echanik` or `(Mechanik|mechanik)` or `(M|m)echanik`.

I know this is not a complete answer, I will expand, if I know more.

Answer (score 2):

From https://projects.kde.org/projects/extragear/office/kile/repository/revisions/master/entry/src/dialogs/findfilesdialog.cpp, `QString FindFilesDialog::buildProjectCommand()` etc., it seems that it is not possible. It would be nice to have and be only a small addition to `kile`, but it's just not there. The hard-coded options passed to `grep` are `-n -E -I -H -e`.

Answer (score 1):

Like Predag says I would suggest using sed. See an introduction here: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html and one for regular expressions here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/.

Comment: I know how to use `sed`, thanks :) But it'd be more convenient to have a "`kile` solution" because it allows to open the files by clicking on the search results without using external apps.